# Type information in a type property

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a type property whose value depends on the class name.  I'd like to write something like this so the property will be computed only once per type:

```
// Doesn't work
static var modifiedClassName: String = {
    let s = type(of: self)
    return String(describing: s).modified()
}()
```

However that doesn't work because `self` is not available within the closure.  The closest I've come is

```
// Works
static var modifiedClassName: String {
    let s = type(of: self)
    return String(describing: s).modified()
}
```

But this property is computed each time it's called and is not what I'm after.

Is there a way to access type information inside a closure defining a type property?

Comment: What about caching the values in a dictionary (with `String(describing: self)` as the key)?

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly include the type annotation of `self` (in the static context), e.g.

```
// dummy modified() method
extension String {
    func modified() -> String { return self }
}

class Foo {
    static let modifiedClassName: String = {
        let s = type(of: Foo.self)
        return String(describing: s).modified()
    }()
}
```

Note that static properties (which are all lazy by default) *do* allow lazy immutable properties, as the one above. Unless you plan to mutate the value of the `modifiedClassName` property (after the once-only instantiation, at first call), you might as well let it be an immutable.

---

It seems difficult to use this in a base class such that the use of `self` is dynamically resolved to the type of derives classes. We may circumvent the inaccess to `self` in your example simply by placing it in a private static method that is called only once: upon instantiation of `modifiedClassName`:

```
extension String {
    func modified() -> String { return self }
}

class Foo {
    static let modifiedClassName: String = _getModifiedClassName()

    class func _getModifiedClassName() -> String {
        let s = type(of: self)
        return String(describing: s).modified()
    }
}
```

But calls to the static property `modifiedClassName` resolve to the base class even if called from a derived class:

```
class Bar: Foo {}

print(Foo.modifiedClassName)       // Foo.Type
print(Bar.modifiedClassName)       // Foo.Type
print(Bar._getModifiedClassName()) // Foo.Type
```

So in this sense, it seems as if `self` is no different from using `Foo` directly in the implementation of `_modifiedClassName()` above.

Possibly possible using Obj-C features.

Comment: This is something I've considered but my goal is that this is a property implementation in a base class so I won't know the type explicitly.

Comment: @sbooth I see, I almost figured as much. I'll see if there's some workaround.

Comment: Nice idea using a class function to encapsulate `self`.

Comment: I originally wanted to implement this functionality in a protocol extension so all types implementing the protocol would inherit the behavior on a per-type basis.  I think for a class there is probably no point to trying to make it dynamic, which perhaps may be why the language disallows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your variable lazily. This means it gets only instantiated when you first call it, which allows you to use self and not have a computed property. Your code only needs a little adjustment.

```
lazy var modifiedClassName: String = {
    let s = type(of: self)
    return String(describing: s).modified()
}()
```

I use this in my code and never seen the instantiation been called more than once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works but results in computing the property once per instance.  I'm trying to compute the property once per type.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Lazy variables are used per instance, but less than every time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:

### Code

```
import Foundation

class Property<T> {

    let modifiedClassName: String
    init () {
        modifiedClassName = String(describing: type(of: T.self)) + Property.modificator
    }
    class var modificator:String {
        return "Class"
    }
}

class Foo {
    static let property1 = Property<Foo>()
    let property2 = Property<Foo>()
}

print("Foo.static.property1 = \(Foo.property1.modifiedClassName)")
let obj = Foo()
print("Foo.property2 = \(obj.property2.modifiedClassName)")
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having a useless property floating around, this works.

```
class Foo {
    static var _modifiedClassNameComputer: String {
        let s = type(of: self)
        return String(describing: s) // .modified()
    }

    static let modifiedClassName = _modifiedClassNameComputer
}

print("\(Foo.modifiedClassName)") // "Foo.Type"
```

Comment: This is similar to @dfri's answer above.  I like the approach.